# Best way to trim and save an existing mp4

Tags: mp4, compression

If I have an existing MP4/H264 video file and I need to trim the start and end,

Then save it as an MP4 again,

Are there any recommendations on export settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool, to do this

#### Without recompression

```
ffmpeg -ss 02:45 -t 03:05 -i orig.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero cut.mp4
```

This will copy a 3m 5s portion of the original MP4, starting at 2m 45s. Since the codec of the video stream in a MP4 usually uses temporal compression, the cutpoints may not be exact and some frames before and after may be included in the trimmed file. Since there's no recompression, quality is identical to the original.

#### With recompression

```
ffmpeg -ss 02:45 -t 03:05 -i orig.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -map 0 cut.mp4
```

This will precisely cut the specified portion but will recompress the content. The `crf` value controls the video quality - smaller value produces better quality but a larger file. The `b:a` sets the bitrate of the audio output.

Comment: this sounds awesome - just googled the steps involved in setting up ffmpeg on my mac and it looks a tad 'challenging' – any non-command line apps available?

Comment: You can download a binary from my first link - no installation needed. Specifically - https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/

Comment: Downloads are .7z files. Not sure what to do with these...

Comment: Wondering if there are any paid GUI apps?

Comment: 7z files are compressed archives like ZIP. Get 7zX from http://7zx.updatestar.com/ and extract the files.

Comment: Does 7z work with Macs?

Comment: 7z is an archive format - it doesn't care about platform. You need a Mac.app which can compress or extract 7z, which the app in my last link does.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MPEG Streamclip for simple editing tasks like that. Just open your file, set in and out point and export again.

Comment: Does MPEG Streamclip allow for trimming/saving/uncompressing MP4s? Thanks

Comment: Well, if it is as simple as selecting a "middle" part of a video - thus cutting off a part of the beginning and the end, it does. Just give it a spin, the software is free and can be downloaded without charge.

Comment: Yes - just trimming bits off - so is it just 'save as mp4' with maximum quality settings for no compression?

Comment: I don't quite understand the export part of your question. There is no such thing as an uncompressed mp4 file. You can save the video uncompressed but typically not in an MP4 container. So if you mean "compressed but with a good quality", suggesting you some settings would require to know the size of your video frame (SD, HD, 4k?)... Generally, converting to a higher bitrate than the video was originally recorded in will obviously not make the video any better then it is.

Comment: As the source file is already an MP4, I'm looking to retain as much quality as possible. Wasn't sure what best export/save settings are when resaving an MP4 as MP4 again from MPEG Streamclip.

Comment: A bitrate if 20-50mbit will create very high quality HD video, probably you will not notice a difference to your original files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use MPEG streamclip! You can set your in and out by using the I and O keys and export to many different codecs. The website is http://www.squared5.com.

I've been using it professionally for years.